# Weird output when using mysql via command line

Tags: mysql, command-line, centos

I am trying to access mysql via command line, but when I enter the command to access my DB, I get the mysql --help text as an output. Here is what I am typing in:

`mysql -h localhost -u USER -p PASSWORD DB_NAME`

I have confirmed all of my credentials are correct, but when I run that, I get the following:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One do...
```

I have also tried running it using php `exec`. I see the same output that way also. Anyone have any thoughts on why this is occurring?

Comment: Recheck the exact syntax of the [`-p` option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between your `-p` flag and your actual password, or use `--password=PASSWORD`. From the [man page](http://man.he.net/?topic=mysql&section=all):

> If you use the short option form (-p), you *cannot* have a space between the option and the password.

Answer (score 1):

Don't include PASSWORD in the command. The "-p" is all you need. It will prompt you for the password without showing the characters you type.